# How to take screenshot of application excluding the statusbar using Appium

Tags: appium-android

### Environment details

1. Appium Version 1.7
2. Android version Nougat

### And below is my code

```
    public class CaptureScreenShot {
    AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;
 Dimension size;
 String destDir;
 DateFormat dateFormat;
 BufferedImage expectedImage;
 BufferedImage actualImage;

 @BeforeTest
 public void setUp() throws Exception {
     DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"Android");
        dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION,"7.0");
        dc.setCapability("deviceName","ce041714c44ebd1802");
        dc.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        dc.setCapability("appPackage", "io.ionic.starter");
        dc.setCapability("appActivity", "io.ionic.starter.MainActivity");
                try {
                    driver= new AppiumDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), dc);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

 }

 @Test
 public void ScrollToTab() {
  takeScreenShot();

 }

 public void takeScreenShot() {
   destDir = "<<local path>>\";

  File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

  dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy__hh_mm_ssaa");

  new File(destDir).mkdirs();

  String destFile = dateFormat.format(new Date()) + ".png";

  try {

   FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(destDir + "/" + destFile));
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
 @Test
 public void verify(){
     try {
        expectedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("<local path>"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
     try {
        actualImage = ImageIO.read(new File("<local path>"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     ImageDiffer imgDiff = new ImageDiffer();
     ImageDiff diff = imgDiff.makeDiff(expectedImage, actualImage);
     Assert.assertFalse(diff.hasDiff(),"Images are Same");
 }

 @AfterTest
 public void End() {
  driver.quit();
 }
}
```

This code works fine but along with the screenshot the android status bar also getting captured and the tests fails as the status screen elements are dynamic.
can anyone help me to take the screenshot without including the status-bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code might solve your problem by taking subImage from full screenshot:

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

AppiumDriver driver;
By locator = By.xpath("(//android.widget.FrameLayout)[1]");
// in my case this locator match everything except status bar

public BufferedImage getSubImage() throws IOException {
    final byte[] srcImage = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).
      getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    final BufferedImage screenshot = ImageIO.read(    
      new ByteArrayInputStream(srcImage));

    final WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
    final Point elementLocation = element.getLocation();
    final Dimension elementSize = element.getSize();
    return screenshot.getSubimage(elementLocation.x, elementLocation.y,
      elementSize.width, elementSize.height);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check and let you know.